# Working with multiple checkboxes in Nextjs14, zod, shadcn/ui and react-hook-form

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, zod, shadcnui

I'm building a form for a client and one of the questions want the user to select a checkbox (or multiple checkboxes). I haven't fully grasped zod's schema so I'm a little stuck on how to implement this.
I tried changing around the schema a couple times, I even mapped through an array of the items I wanted to be checked and rendered them as checkboxes but I was unsuccessful.

I'm also trying to assign string to the checkboxes (i'm not using them for true and false questions).

Here's my form field:

```
<FormField
    name="reservationMethod"
    control={form.control}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem className="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <FormLabel className="text-base md:text-lg text-black font-extralight">
                Which of the following did you use to make your
                reservation?
            </FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
                <div className="flex gap-4">
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                        <Checkbox
                            id="tourOperator"
                            value="Tour Operator"
                            checked={field.value.includes("Tour Operator")}
                            onCheckedChange={() =>
                                handleCheckboxChange("Tour Operator")
                            }
                        />
                        <Label htmlFor="tourOperator">Tour Operator</Label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                        <Checkbox
                            id="internet"
                            value="Internet"
                            checked={field.value.includes("Internet")}
                            onCheckedChange={() =>
                                handleCheckboxChange("Internet")
                            }
                        />
                        <Label htmlFor="internet">Internet</Label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                        <Checkbox
                            id="directlyWithResort"
                            value="Directly with the resort"
                            checked={field.value.includes(
                                "Directly with the resort"
                            )}
                            onCheckedChange={() =>
                                handleCheckboxChange("Directly with the resort")
                            }
                        />
                        <Label htmlFor="directlyWithResort">
                            Directly with the resort
                        </Label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                        <Checkbox
                            id="travelAgent"
                            value="Travel Agent"
                            checked={field.value.includes("Travel Agent")}
                            onCheckedChange={() =>
                                handleCheckboxChange("Travel Agent")
                            }
                        />
                        <Label htmlFor="travelAgent">Travel Agent</Label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex justify-center items-center ml-10">
                        <Label>Name of agency: </Label>
                        <Input type="text" {...field} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </FormControl>
        </FormItem>
    )}
/>
```

My schema for that specific field: `reservationMethod: z.string().array(),`

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue with you schema. The correct way of defining your schema is:

```
const schema = z.object({
  // ... other fields ...
  reservationMethod: z.array(z.string()),
});
```

Then you'll need to ensure that the `field.value` is an array and that you correctly handle the addition and removal of checkbox values when they are checked or unchecked. The `handleCheckboxChange` function should update the `reservationMethod` field in your form state to reflect the current selections.

`handleCheckboxChange` should be something like this:

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (checkedValue) => {
  const currentValue = form.control.getFieldValue("reservationMethod") || [];
  if (currentValue.includes(checkedValue)) {
    // If the checkbox is currently checked, remove it from the array
    form.control.setValue(
      "reservationMethod",
      currentValue.filter(value => value !== checkedValue)
    );
  } else {
    // If the checkbox is not checked, add it to the array
    form.control.setValue(
      "reservationMethod",
      [...currentValue, checkedValue]
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Turns out shadcn had a template for using multiple checboxes along with forms.
Link: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/checkbox#form